# How do I get user information within a stateless session bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm working on an existing j2ee app and am required to remove some vendor specific method calls from the code.

The daos behind a session facade make calls into the ejb container to get the user's id and password - in order to connect to the database.  The user id and password part of the initialContext used to connect to the server.

I am able to get the userid using `sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()`

Is there anyway to get to the `SECURITY_CREDENTIALS` used on the server connection or, is there a way to pass information from the server connection into the ejbs (they are all stateless session beans).

This is a large app with both a rich-client and web front end, and in a perfect world I'd be happy to go back and re-architect the entire solution to use J2EE security etc - but unfortunately, that is not realistic.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a generic solution, but this is what has worked for us.  We have the app server connect to LDAP as a specific user that has the ability to request credentials for other users.  Then we have some generic security code that we can use to request a users credentials from inside the session beans, based on the users identity from their initial login (just as you are doing it via `getCallerPrincipal()`).

We also place the users identity in a thread local variable, so that classes down the call chain from the EJB do not have to be "container aware".  They simply access the identity from the thread local and use the security classes to look up user profile information.  This also makes it easy to change the implementation for testing, or even something other than LDAP lookups.

Other conveniences we created were a `JDBCServiceLocator` that retrieves connections with user/password for the current user.  So the developer does not have to explicitly code the security lookups at all.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Java EE security model will not allow the retrieval of the user password, for security reasons. But it depends on the implementation. Some vendors provide methods to retrieve this kind of information, but if you rely on such implementations, be aware that the portability of the application will be compromised.

One common approach is to write a servlet filter to intercept the login request and save a copy of the credentials, to be used later. If your application doesn't use the Java EE security infrastructure, this could be easily implemented. That's because some vendors prevent you from filtering an authentication servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Robin,

Sounds like what I was planning.  I figured I'd make a call right after a successful server connection to load the credentials into a threadLocal variable on my connection class.  I was hoping there was an easier way - but I guess not.